comma separated values to a one column in excel
i just got hired in my first IT position and im trying to optimize some of their excel sheets.i've been trying to solve this get my head around this but no luck.excuse me i am a newbie in excel environement.


If your version of Excel supports it then you can use =TEXTSPLIT(A1,,","); otherwise you can use Text-to-Columns, Copy the result of that and then Paste -> Paste Special -> Transpose.

click on the column that has the comma separated values, in the data menu at the top there should be a button that says "text to columns" click it and follow the promp but make sure to choose delimiter comma and not (semicolon, tab, etc) and click next until it has imported the values into columns
then select the cells that have the values and copy them (ctrl+c) and go to new sheet or wherever you want to paste it, RIGHT click on a cell and click Paste Special and select the checkbox beside Transpose
this should give you desired result
